# How to update (put) without refreshing with ajax in laravel 6?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to update my data without the page having to refresh every time by using ajax. I haven't really used ajax in the past so this is very new to me. I've tried a few different ways from examples I've seen and this is what I could put together for now.

At the moment it gives me an error `The PUT method is not supported for this route.` and the url above stays the same.

This is what I've currently tried:

**Blade**

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
      <span class="td">Name</span>
      <span class="td">New cases</span>
      <span class="td">cases</span>
      <span class="td">deaths</span>
      <span class="td">recoveries</span>
      <span class="td">Submit</span>
    </div>

        @foreach($data as $dat)
        <form class="tr" id="form{{$dat->id}}">
          <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="csrf_token" />
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$dat->id}}">
          @method('put')
          <span class="td"><input type="text" name="name" value="{{$dat->country_name}}"/></span>
          <span class="td"><input type="text" name="nCases" value="{{$dat->new_cases}}"/></span>
          <span class="td"><input type="text" name="cases" value="{{$dat->cases}}"/></span>
          <span class="td"><input type="text" name="deaths" value="{{$dat->deaths}}"/></span>
          <span class="td"><input type="text" name="recoveries" value="{{$dat->recoveries}}"/></span>
          <span class="td"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></span>
        </form>
        @endforeach
</div>
```

**Script below**

```
<script>
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        action: {{url("/ajaxtest")}},
        type: 'put',
        data: $('form').serialize(), 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function( _response ){
            // Handle error
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
    public function ajaxTest(Request $request) {
        $id = \Request::input('id');
        $cases = \Request::input('cases');
        $nCases = \Request::input('nCases');
        $deaths = \Request::input('deaths');
        $recoveries = \Request::input('recoveries');

        Countries::where("id", $id)->update([
            'cases' => $cases,
            'deaths' => $deaths,
            'new_cases' => $nCases,
            'recoveries' => $recoveries
            ]);
    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::put('/ajaxtest', 'CountriesController@ajaxTest');
```

Comment: What about your routes?

Comment: @RubenDanielyan added the routes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have `@method("put")` in your blade, so when you serialize the form, this input value is already in your data:

```
// serialized data looks like
{
    ...
    "_method": "put"
}
```

All you need is to change ajax type from `put` to `post`, this has to help

Also you don't have to have `@csrf` in every form, just have 1 input for the page and set its value to your ajax headers

```
// in blade
<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="csrf_token" />

// in js
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
let token = $("#csrf_token").val();
$.ajax({
    action: {{url("/ajaxtest")}},
    type: 'post', // CHANGE this line from put to post
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token }, // ADD token to headers
    data: $(this).serialize(), // serialize the form submitted
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function( _response ){
        // Handle error
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Hi, thank you for you response. I've tried what you suggested but for some reason whenever I  click on submit on my form it still wants to reload my page and nothing appears in the console at all. Would you know why this is?

Comment: try to add event.stopPropagation()  after enent.preventDefault()

Comment: Manage to fix that issue now. When I click on submit and check the console it does give me `POST <url goes here> 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: Found the issue, for some reason whenever I redirect the route to my controller it gives me a 500 error but when I apply it in the routes it returns 'some data'

Comment: Have you managed to access your method via ajax put request now?

Comment: I've got it to work in the route (web.php) page but not by sending it to my controller since this still gives me a 500 error. Also it updates the latest id and not the id I submit to. Updated the main post to my edits now.

Comment: Please show your existing code and error you get, if you only get 500 server error with no message then set `APP_DEBUG=true` in .env and run `php artisan config:cache`, I can't help you without seeing your handler and error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208760/discussion-between-ruben-danielyan-and-n212).